# does rosbag play guarantee data during its playback?

Tags: ros, playback, loss, rosbag

I am currently working on developing ROS nodes. One node is for parsing raw lidar data which is gained from *.bag* file and publish to a topic, and the other node subscribes the parsed data from the first node and publish a bunch of the parsed point cloud data by gathering for a specific time duration.

However, the point cloud data seems not to be published to nodes with its correct amount of data.
When I play the .bag file with 0.1 rate, the point cloud data seems not to have much loss data, but when it plays with its normal speed, then it much data gets lost.

For example,

- `rosbag play data.bag`
  : (result) point cloud # 60000~80000
  (normal speed)
- `rosbag play data.bag --rate=0.1`
  : (result) point cloud # 1000~1100
  (10times slower speed)

according to the result above, when the data is played with the normal speed it loses almost 50% of its data.

Do you have any idea to get the full data with its normal play speed?

Comment: It depends on your system capacity and the queue sizes. See: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Choosing_a_good_queue_size